# How to test multiple sequential calls with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I am trying to test a function that unsubscribes from all subscriptions:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.tryUnsubscribe(this.carsSubscription);
        this.tryUnsubscribe(this.partsSubscription);
        this.tryUnsubscribe(this.shopsSubscription);
    }
```

This is the test I wrote for the function:

```
it('should unsubscribe from subscriptions ', () => { 
      spyOn(component, "tryUnsubscribe");     
      component.ngOnDestroy();
      expect(component.tryUnsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component['carsSubscription']);
      expect(component.tryUnsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component['partsSubscription']);
      expect(component.tryUnsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component['shopsSubscription']);
    });
```

The problem:

If I comment out a function call, the tests still passes.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.tryUnsubscribe(this.carsSubscription);
        //this.tryUnsubscribe(this.partsSubscription);
        this.tryUnsubscribe(this.shopsSubscription);
    }
```

Only if I comment out all of these function calls, the test fails:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        //this.tryUnsubscribe(this.carsSubscription);
        //this.tryUnsubscribe(this.partsSubscription);
        //this.tryUnsubscribe(this.shopsSubscription);
    }
```

How to properly test this kind of function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you log out all those ``component['...']`` just before assertions?

Comment: @Buczkowski They all log out undefined, because I'm defining these subscriptions only when I create  a subscription in the TS code of the component.

Comment: This is the reason why it passes even you are commenting out some of method execution. It will be all asserted like called with ``undefined``. How about checking it with called times? Like tryUnsubscribe called 3 times?

Comment: Ok, can you provide an answer with a code sample? I will upvote it and if no one here comes up with a better solution today, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would rewrite your test to the following:

```
it('should unsubscribe from subscriptions ', () => { 
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'tryUnsubscribe');     
  component.ngOnDestroy();

  // Check how many times the spy was called
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
});
```

If you now uncomment one of the `tryUnsubscribe` calls, the test should fail as the spy was only called twice.

Another approach would be to mock the subscriptions or just set them to a dummy value to test that inside the `ngDestroy` `tryUnsubscribe` was called with those 3 component variables:

```
it('test unsubscribing', () => {
  // Mock values
  component.carsSubscription = Observable.of(1).subscribe(() => {});
  component.partsSubscription = Observable.of(1).subscribe(() => {});
  component.shopsSubscription = Observable.of(1).subscribe(() => {});

  const spy = spyOn(component, 'tryUnsubscribe').and.callThrough();     
  component.ngOnDestroy();

  // Check how many times the spy was called
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);

  // Check arguments
  expect(spy.calls.all()[0].args[0]).toEqual(component.carsSubscription);
  expect(spy.calls.all()[1].args[0]).toEqual(component.partsSubscription);
  expect(spy.calls.all()[2].args[0]).toEqual(component.shopsSubscription);
});
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-5yubvc?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.ts)
>   is a working stackblitz with the test.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to check all arguments at once using Jasmine calls.allArgs() method:

```
expect(spy.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
  [component.carsSubscription],
  [component.partsSubscription],
  [component.shopsSubscription]
]);
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-3w9xeq?file=app/dummy/dummy.component.spec.ts) is modified Fabian Küng's answer in stackblitz.